# Counting elements in a list (haskell)

Tags: haskell

this is a small part of my homework, i have to count the elements of a list and if the count == 2 then return true. the elements of that list are not fixed but are filtered using a **different function** for example allNumbers. I have to use this existing function to check if it has 2 elements or not.

the definition of the checking function would be:

```
isTrue :: Int -> Bool
```

I have a current function defined

```
divisors :: Int -> [Int]
divisors n | n < 1 = []
           | otherwise = filter (\k -> n `mod` k == 0) [1..n]
```

What this does is lists all numbers that divide n. now I need to make another function isTrue in the same program that will give true if the list that is produced by the above function has only two numbers.

Comment: The list produced by `divisors` can contain only numbers, because it is said to be a list of `Int`s. Did you mean "[...] has only *2* numbers"?

Comment: thanks for your reply. yes the list is a list of Int's, I meant isTrue is a different function that returns true if the list produced by divisors contains only 2 elements. so I am guessing it will be in the condition of when n > 1 but now sure how to implement it here.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I understand, you need a function taking a list and returning a boolean value. Thus, the signature should be something like:

```
doit :: [a] -> Bool

doit (x:y:z) = True -- matches if the list contains at least 2 elements
doit _ = False      -- matches otherwise (i.e. list has 0 or 1 element)

-- or, we match only if the length is exactly 2

newdoit :: [a] -> Bool
newdoit [a,b] = True
newdoit _ = False

-- or even more elegant
simpledoit l = (length l)==2

-- the complete function is then e.g.
completefunc l = newdoit (divisors l)
```

Comment: I made a mistake in my question. the function isTrue is supposed to return true if count of the list = 2. anything other than that is false.

Comment: thanks. but how do I use the result (list) of the other function in place of [Int] or [a] ?

Comment: `simpledoit (otherfunction mylist)`, btw: do you know this? http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters

Comment: I advise against using `length l == 2` unless you **know** that `l` is short. If `l` is long (or worse, infinite) you waste a _lot_ of time calculating the length. Instead of `length list == k`, use `case drop (k-1) list of { [_] -> True; _ -> False; }` not as pretty, but no horrible performance surprises.

Comment: I'm getting confused here :S , my question was asking something very simple I guess, I have edited the question to make it more clearer.

Answer (score 4):

I don't want to give away the whole solution, but I think it's worth pointing out that besides going for some solution which uses the [`length`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3alength) function to compute the length of the list and then yielding an appropriate result, you could also consider to use [pattern matching](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching) here, because the length you compare with (2) is pretty small. So something like

```
hasLengthOfTwo <pattern_matching_lists_with_two_elements> = True
hasLengthOfTwo _ = False
```

A small (probably irrelevant) advantage of this is that it also works on infinite lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
length' xs = case ((length xs) > 2) of
                  True -> True
                  _ -> False
```

Comment: Uh, c'mon, then at least `length' xs = (length xs) > 2` please.